# Patent for full body teleportation system using wormholes

Tags: gravitational-waves, wormholes, quantum-teleportation

A friend has shown me this, and I'm quite interested
1) why this is an official patent if it wouldn't work
2) and if it would work, why isn't it already created?

> ABSTRACT
>
> Full body teleportation system 
>   A pulsed gravitational wave wormhole generator system that teleports a human being through hyperspace from one location to another.

[Full body teleportation system Patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060071122)

Comment: patents do not need to be for things that work or can work (there is a special case for perpetual motion machines)

Comment: Ahham. So it can be just gibberish.

Comment: Heck, there are actual products you can buy that don't work - why should you think something on a piece of paper has to?

Comment: Hi Nicole, I edited in the first line of the abstract, as many users dislike going off site unnecessarily.  Thanks

Comment: The patent is psuedoscientific nonsense. The patent descriptions begins with a psuedoscience claim that the patenter experienced teleportation themselves `The basis for this invention is an event, referring to FIG. 1, occurring on May 2, 2004, in which the inventor (“he”) personally experienced a full-body teleportation while walking to the bus stop`.

Additionally, the US PTO has a history of low quality patents. ArsTechnica explains why this happens in great detail: 
https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/12/these-experts-figured-out-why-so-many-bogus-patents-get-approved/

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, anyone can patent anything, it does not have to work even in theory, if you have some data behind it you can patent it

To answer your second question...
I cannot provide an argument that is backed by maths or real data, but I would imagine that there are a couple limiting factors here.

One:
Gravitational waves while theorized were not even proven to have existed until earlier this year (2016). [See the reporting of it here](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/02/gravitational-waves-einsteins-ripples-spacetime-spotted-first-time)

Two:
I would guess that this would take an inordinate amount of power, that is purely speculation but with what they are describing it does sound like a lot of power is needed.